# function pointers in python

Tags: python, function-pointers

I would like to do something like the following:

```
def add(a, b):
    #some code

def subtract(a, b):
    #some code

operations = [add, subtract]
operations[0]( 5,3)
operations[1](5,3)
```

In python, is it possible to assign something like a function pointer?

Comment: Try actually executing that code in the interactive environment and see what happens.

Comment: I'm tempted to delete the silly [function-pointer] and [anonymous-methods] tags because they don't makes sense in Python.  But then, this kind of question shows that Python lacks those complexities.

Comment: you're in luck, my friend, but they're neither anonymous nor unbound

Comment: I think by "unbound functions" he meant "functions, not methods".

Comment: No, "unbound functions" is a hair-splitting in C++ and "prothon" to explain functions that are not (yet) bound to a class, but could be.  And Java folks have to give functions fancy-sounding names.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you try it? What you wrote works exactly as written. Functions are first-class objects in Python.

Answer (score 9):

Python has nothing called pointers, but your code works as written.  Function are first-class objects, assigned to names, and used as any other value.

You can use this to implement a Strategy pattern, for example:

```
def the_simple_way(a, b):
    # blah blah

def the_complicated_way(a, b):
    # blah blah

def foo(way):
    if way == 'complicated':
        doit = the_complicated_way
    else:
        doit = the_simple_way

    doit(a, b)
```

Or a lookup table:

```
def do_add(a, b):
    return a+b

def do_sub(a, b):
    return a-b

handlers = {
    'add': do_add,
    'sub': do_sub,
}

print handlers[op](a, b)
```

You can even grab a method bound to an object:

```
o = MyObject()
f = o.method
f(1, 2) # same as o.method(1, 2)
```

Comment: If they are not called "function pointers", what do you call them? Just function as in my mind, a function is either the definition or its call that includes the parentheses. But I am no expert.

Comment: If you do this:   `def foo(): ...;  bar = foo`  then foo and bar are both names referring to a function. There is no difference between them.  So if foo is a function, then why isn't bar a function?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note that most Python operators already have an equivalent function in the [operator](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module.